# How to prevent 2 seperate meshes that have soft-body modifiers from clipping into each other and glitching, even if collision is turned on?

Tags: physics, soft-body

What I want to achieve : 2-5 meshes all of which have soft-body modifier. I needed them to bounce onto each other, flop off each other, etc.

What I have done so far : Created 2 meshes. Have a plane right below them acting as a surface to bounce on. All 3 of them have a collision modifier. The initial 2 meshes have a soft-body modifier in addition. Soft-Body self-collision has not been enabled, as this itself took an hour to bake. I'm planning to apply this to 5 meshes, rather than just 2, so bake times are crucial for me

Problem : Even when I delete every bake in the scene, re-add a collision modifier + soft-body to the 2 meshes in the scene, the sim starts off with the 2 meshes wrapping around each other, intersecting and clipping into each other, all whilst remaining in the same place, not falling to the ground.

Here is a link to my file : [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16izimVrAsGyc6dB0YLxMDlUWg2vKf4jF/view?usp=sharing)

Here is a video of my issue, apologies for bad video trimming and quality :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As with all simulations, start by ensuring you have ‘applied scale’ on each mesh and that the Normals are pointing in the correct direction.

Next, check the ‘cloth and soft body’ settings on each collision modifier - turn the Inner and Outer right down. If you still get intersections, turn the Inner up slightly until it is resolved (but not too high).

Also, you should avoid starting the simulation with intersecting meshes since this can cause very large forces at the start of the simulation.

Comment: I have already done applying scale and normals, and even rebaked with the meshes far away from each other. The issue still continues to happen

Comment: I have tried turning down inner and outter down like you said. It stops that horrid wringing effect, but now, there is zero collision between both meshes. They only collide with surface, Is there any way to know the optimal inner and outer values for each mesh?

Comment: Looking at your .blend, the meshes appear to be non-manifold, which can cause problems with soft body and collision. Typically, you should set Inner to not more than half of the narrowest part of the mesh. eg, if mesh is 0.1 blender units at its narrowest the. Make sure you don’t set Inner less than 0.05 or you risk the collision from the opposite face dragging vertices through the mesh. Also, you get a better simulation if the faces are approximately square and of similar size to each other - so either retopologise or apply a remesh modifier after you’ve made it “manifold”.

Comment: Nonmanifold means it isn't a closed shape right? Both meshes look close to me. Also, how do I know how thick the thinnest part of the mesh is. Anyway to measure it?

Comment: Quite right - I’ve just reopened them on a different computer and they do look manifold now (I think I have a problem on the system I opened it on first). You don’t need to be too accurate with the distance - so just estimate and then subtract a bit to be sure... it’s just to ensure the ‘inner’ region doesn’t protrude through the opposite face. I believe there an addon to measure distances.

Comment: Don’t forget to Delete Bake after you have made any changes. Also, you should get better results by combining the meshes into a single objects so they are both within the same soft body simulation (and remove the collision modifier from it). You’ll need to enable self-collision but this shouldn’t be too bad if you aren’t having collision on the softbody itself. If your ‘inner’ on the other meshes is appropriate you should be able to reduce the max steps in the solver and still get a good sim (more quickly).

Comment: I have already deleted bake multiple times, and even deleted all modifiers and started over. Self collision on one mesh itself pushes my bake times incredibly high. I have over 200k tris worth of meshes to bake in my final render. Also how do I estimate the size and subtract what exactly?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention one last thing. What units do soft body inner and out operate in? Blender units?

Comment: I believe it’s whatever units you have your scene set to - Blender Units by default.

Comment: Thank you. Just one last question just to make sure. Inner shouldn't be more than half the narrowest part of the mesh. What about outter? How big should it be?

Comment: At the Outer distance the cloth will be repelled from the mesh - so too high a value will result in a gap between the surface and the cloth/soft body. It’s also important to make sure the meshes aren’t intersecting at the start and the Outer is included in this (you don’t want a mesh to start within the Outer region of another. Start with the lowest value and increase it slightly if you end up being able to see one mesh slightly overlapping with the other - it basically allows you to set the minimum separation between the cloth and the surface.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my issue!

Comment: I ran into a similar  issue now, wherein 2 softbody meshes don't even collide with each other, but only with the ground? What values do I tweak for this? One mesh has both outer and inner turned down to 0.001 since its thin. Steps were raised to min 400 and max 800, yet this issue still happens

Comment: Perhaps best to start a new question on this one (it's better with 1 question for 1 issue) - post a link to it here and I can take a look when I get the chance.

Comment: Here is the link to my question [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186418/how-to-prevent-two-soft-bodies-from-clipping-into-each-other-in-a-soft-body-sim)